# Preg match in expression with array

Tags: php, regex

I'm getting `syntax error, unexpected '{'` in the following line:

`} elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/',$msz['letters']) {`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you paste the full PHP snippet please?

Comment: what for? the `$msz['letters]` is defined

Comment: How about you count opening and closing round brackets …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing `)` after `$msz['letters']`.

Comment: omg... :D I'm an idiot! thanks, Sebastian!